# Angular service An argument for 'model' was not provided

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a service and it accepts id as paramter and I am requesting the route with the id but I received the error above on my service . Any idea?

[image]

#service

```
const apiBaseUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/userprofile`;


    deactivateUserProfileStatus(id: number) {
        return this.httpRequestService.put(`${apiBaseUrl}/inactive/${id}`);
      }
```

#ts

```
DeactivateUserProfileStatus(id: number) {
    this.isInProgress = true;
    this._userService
      .deactivateUserProfileStatus(id)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.isInProgress = false;
        })
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this._notificationService.showSuccess(
            'User status has been updated successfully.'
          );
          // this.generalForm.disable();
          this.getUserGeneralDetails();
          // this._router.navigate(['transactions']);
        },
        error: (err) => {
          this._notificationService.showError(
            'Something went wrong, Try again later.'
          );
          this.isInProgress = false;
        },
        complete: () => {
          this.isInProgress = false;
        },
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the body (or atleast empty body) for your `PUT` request.

```
(method) HttpClient.put(url: string, body: any, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: "body";
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType: "arraybuffer";
    withCredentials?: boolean; 
}): Observable<...> (+14 overloads)
```

the only `GET` requests call without body just by URL.

Comment: I have added a detail above Sir

Comment: still the same errir

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: deactivateUserProfileStatus(id: number) {
    return this.httpRequestService.put(`${apiBaseUrl}/inactive/${id}`, id);
  }         ????

Comment: dude! you are about to make a web-service request, all web services have a header, body, and options! in `PUT` method you are forced to pass the body to the `httpClient` function